# Digit regex causes jshint 'Bad or unnecessary escaping' error

Tags: javascript, regex, jshint

I have a very, very, simple Regexp:

```
new RegExp('\d')
```

[`/d` is valid according to MDN's RegExp docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Running jshint gives:

```
Bad or unnecessary escaping.
```

For the line. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: @epascarello if this is a duplicate, please tell me what question it's a duplicate of.

Comment: You construct a regular expression in one of two ways:

Using a regular expression literal, as follows:

    var re = /\d/;
    new RegExp(re);
Regular expression literals provide compilation of the regular expression when the script is loaded. When the regular expression will remain constant, use this for better performance.

Comment: Calling the constructor function of the RegExp object, as follows:

    var re = new RegExp("\\d");
    new RegExp(re);
Using the constructor function provides runtime compilation of the regular expression. Use the constructor function when you know the regular expression pattern will be changing, or you don't know the pattern and are getting it from another source, such as user input. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide%2FRegular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags

Comment: @AmirPopovich Makes sense. I thought //d would mean literally 'slash d', rather than 'digit', but I can see from your MDN link it's correct.

Comment: There's a link to the duplicate at the top of the question.

Comment: This is jshint, that is jslint, which is **a different piece of software with a different error message**. While the answer is the same, the question is obviously different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to again escape `\d`,

```
new RegExp("\\d")
```

`\` should be escaped in the regex which has `"`  as  delimiter.

Comment: Thanks. Why do I have to escape twice though? What does each of the two escapes do?

Comment: if we use `/` as delimiters then you could use the normal regex as it is. But when the regex is enclosed within `"`, then we need to escape one more time. Also in Java , regexes are enclosed within double quotes. This type of escaping is avoided when we put the regex inside verbatim string , ie `@""`, c# has this feature.

Comment: I understand we need to escape one more time when using the constructor. But why?

Comment: @mikemaccana because otherwise JS would think you're trying to escape quotes instead of regex symbols. `var test = 'hello what\'s up?';`